# WPF RibbonComboBox Style vs. Combobox Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ribbon

My situation is this:

We have a WPF application using a WPF ribbon(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534(v=vs.100).aspx). We have a scenario where we use both the RibbonComboBox as well as "normal" ComboBox in the ribbon, where the ComboBox is referenced via a ControlTemplate.

The issue we have, is that the default ComboBox style is different to the RibbonComboBox style, which is a bit of an eyesore. How can we determine what the Style / ControlTemplate of the RibbonComboBox is so that we can apply the same / something similar to the "normal" ComboBox, without having to go and scratch around in the MS code.

If gone through MSDN after MSDN article and I've scoured stackoverflow and nowhere can I find this info?

Thanks!

Comment: You can get the style of RibbonComboBox using Microsoft Blend. Similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615502/how-to-style-ribboncombobox

Comment: Mmm - I see the poster used ILSpy to eventually get to the ControlTemplate for the RibbonControl - something I was hoping to avoid. MS has the styles for the default ComboBox posted on MSDN(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334408%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), but not yet for the RibbonComboBox :-( My quick an easy solution would be to not use the RibbonComboBoxes for now and just use the normal ComboBoxes so I can enforce a singular style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following link for getting style of your RibbonComboBox using Blend.

http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/using-blend-to-find-default-style-xaml/

Comment: Thanks Victory Jessie. I've created a RibbonComboBox item in Blend for VS2013, but when I try and 'Edit Template - Edit a Copy' it doesn't allow me to...frustrating. Going to play around some more and see if I can get at the Template.