# RibbonComboBox doesn't display selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, ribbon

Very simple program. Maybe too simple? 
XMAL:

```
<RibbonComboBox x:Name="cbxRibbonCommsGroupBaud"  LargeImageSource="Resource/Cheetah.png">
   <RibbonGallery Name="RBaudGGallery" SelectionChanged="RBaudGGallery_OnSelectionChanged">
       <RibbonGalleryCategory Name="RBaudGGalleryC" ItemsSource="{Binding}"></RibbonGalleryCategory>
   </RibbonGallery>
</RibbonComboBox>
```

The code behind:

```
private int[] baudRateList = { 9600, 19200, 38400, 57600, 115200, 230400, 460800, 921600 };
cbxRibbonCommsGroupBaud.Items.Clear();
cbxRibbonCommsGroupBaud.ItemsSource = baudRateList;
```

When I run the program, the items are in the combobox drop down but when I select the item, it doesn't stay and the box appears empty. Also, RBaudGGallery_OnSelectionChanged is never called. So I'm missing something but have no clue what since other combo boxes are working just fine that aren't in the ribbon. I'm using the Reference of System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you have a SelectedItem binding set?

```
SelectedItem = {Binding mySelectedBaud}
```

[How to databind SelectedItem of RibbonComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555449/how-to-databind-selecteditem-of-ribboncombobox)

Comment: That's what I left out. New to WPF in general so am still learning the binding that goes on. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I'm still learning, the learning curve is steep especially with Xaml. Keep plugging away & you'll get there

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have found another answer : IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" on the RibbonGallery control sets the SelectedItem correctly

```
<RibbonGallery 
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRule, Mode=TwoWay}" 
  x:Name="RulesItems" >
      <RibbonGalleryCategory 
             ItemsSource="{Binding RulesCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"          
             DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" />
</RibbonGallery>
```