# Modify selected RibbonComboxBox item by code

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I try to modify selected item by code of a RibbonComboBox:

```
<r:RibbonComboBox x:Name="RibbonComboxBoxEditEnemyProjectiles" Label="Projectile"   SmallImageSource="img/history16.png">
    <r:RibbonGallery SelectedItem="{Binding Path=iSpriteIdx}" >
        <r:RibbonGalleryCategory ItemsSource="{Binding oProjectiles, Source={StaticResource GameInfos}}" />
    </r:RibbonGallery>
</r:RibbonComboBox>
```

I try 2 ways :

```
RibbonGalleryEditProjectileSprite.SelectedItem  = GameData.oSprites[ idx ];
RibbonGalleryEditProjectileSprite.SelectedValue = GameData.oSprites[ idx ];
```

This ways don't work. What is a correct way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "This ways don't work" ? Please provide more details e.g. if control is not updated or it throw any exception.

Comment: Sorry for the answer time.
"Don't work" == "Control is not updated & no exception

Answer (score 1):

If you search this website before you post questions, you can find good answers... Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555449/how-to-databind-selecteditem-of-ribboncombobox) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107992/how-to-set-selecteditem-on-a-ribboncombobox-using-mvvm).

UPDATE >>>

The [How to set SelectedItem on a RibbonComboBox using MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107992/how-to-set-selecteditem-on-a-ribboncombobox-using-mvvm) post that I gave you a link for has a complete solution for you. Basically the answer is this:

Whatever object that you set as the `RibbonGallery.DataContext` should have a collection property to bind to the `RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemsSource` property and a property of the same type as the collection items to bind to the `RibbonGallery SelectedItem` property.

Let's say that your selected item property is called `SelectedItem`. You will then be able to set the `SelectedItem` property of the object that you set as the `RibbonGallery.DataContext` to an item from the collection and the binding will change the selected item in the `RibbonGallery` UI.

Note that if you are using objects as your gallery data types (as opposed to primitives like `string`, etc.), then this will only work if you set your `SelectedItem` property to an *actual* item from the collection and not just one with the same values. This can be easily achieved if your data object has a property with unique values by the following:

```
DataContextData.SelectedItem = DataContextData.CollectionData.Where(d => d.Id == 
itemToSelect.Id).Single();
```

If that still hasn't helped, I did a quick search online and found a complete solution that you can download and examine at your leisure in the [How do I add Galleries to my Ribbon?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/08/04/how-do-i-add-galleries-to-my-ribbon.aspx) post at 'The official blog of the Windows Presentation Foundation Team'. It shows a good example of the method that I just described.

Comment: Any body have any idea to do that?
I do not find a way to modify RibbonComboxBox selectedItem/selectedValue by code...

Comment: Thanks, I search on stackoverflow but apparently not with a correct keyword.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark it as so by clicking on the green tick, so other users know.